# Karma Not Running - cannot find module gulp

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, gulp, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up karma tests with Jasmine on my Angular project.

I can't get basic test

```
`it("dummy", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);`
```

to run, and I'm getting the error:

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'

This is my gulp test task:

```
gulp.task('test', function(coverage) {
   gulp.src('dummy')
   .pipe(karma({
   configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
   action: 'run'
  }))
  .on('error', function(err) {
      // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
      throw err;
  });
```

});

And this is my karma conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],

    plugins : [
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'src/app/**/*.spec.js': [ 'browserify' ], 
      'src/components/**/*.spec.js': [ 'browserify' ], 
      'src/services/**/*.spec.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/**/*.js',
      'src/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Please help me stackoverflow you're my only hope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common question: did you install gulp correctly?

```
npm install gulp
```

Also check which files you are loading into the `files` property in `karma.conf.js`. There should be only your 3rd party libraries js files, your custom js files and your test files.

There's also a chance that your gulp task is not correct but since I often use grunt, I can't really help in that part :P

Comment: Nailed it. I was loading in files in the karma.conf files property with the ***.* glob. Working nicely now thanks very much you are a star.